# VBA detect if a column format is date

Tags: excel, vba

How can I check if a **column** (**not a cell or range!!!**) is in Date format.

The following code shows the column format but how to list all the possible date formats ([$-C09]dddd, d mmmm yyyy;@,d/mm/yyyy;@...) the macro detect when the format is changed?

```
Sub Macro1()
MsgBox Selection.NumberFormat
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `a column (not a cell or range!!!)` - a column is a range, and a range is a collection of cells. Number format is applied to *cells*. If all selected calls have the same number format, `Selection.NumberFormat` shows it, otherwise it returns `Null`.

Comment: Slightly confused with your query. Do you mean you want to return the date format which is used maximum in a column? For example if there are 5 cells which are filled with date and 3 of them are `dd/mm/yyyy` and 2 of them are `m/d/yyyy` then you want to return  `dd/mm/yyyy`? **OR** do you want to return both formats? **OR** If the 5 cells have different formats (text, number, date) then retun all?

Comment: My problem is how do I enumerate all the date format possibilities that NumberFormat returns?

Comment: In other terms How do I check that the format name at the top of my image is indeed DATE?

Comment: If you have mixed formats in the column then that numberformat which you see will be for the first cell in that column and not for the rest of the data in that column.

Comment: `NumberFormat` has infinite number of possibilities. You cannot enumerate them.

Comment: So no way to determine if a column is Date?

Comment: Okay, let's try it differently. WHY do you want to know the dates in this column or other data? (perhaps we again encountered [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and your problem is solved much easier)

Comment: `So no way to determine if a column is Date? – user3387046 16 mins ago` Refer to my first comment. If the column has mixed formats (as shown in your pic) then what should be the result? column is Date or not? If yes, then what is the ciriteria for deciding it is date? Check for maximum date format types?

Comment: The purpose is to populate a Listbox with the column headers in the sheet. If a picked column header pertains to a "Date" column, the user is presented with the choice to analyze the relevant column in  Month or Year resolution. It can work if only I know if the column is Date

Comment: If say Col A is that column and A1 has a text header and rest of the cells have dates then yes it is easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: Looking for something robust without criteria

Comment: Can you give couple of example of columns which according to you is date?

Comment: `It can work if only I know if the column is Date` - you cannot know that. You can call `IsDate` on each cell of the column individually, but you may become disappointed or confused with the results. Proceed on the assumption that they are dates, fail when an error is encountered.

Comment: You can tell if a cell has a date format applied with a single line of code:  `Left(Evaluate("=CELL(""format""," & rg.Address & ")"), 1) = "D"`  But to check the entire column, you'll need to loop through every cell.  And I don't know of any event triggered with a change in the number format. You can intercept the `Selection_Change` event and check to see if the numberformat was changed, though.